# c select() reading until null character

Tags: c, sockets, proxy

I am implementing a proxy in c and am using select() to not block on I/O. There are multiple clients connecting to the proxy, so I include the socket descriptor # in my messages so that I know to which socket to forward a reply message from the server.

However, sometimes read() will not receive the full message up to the null character, but will send the rest of the message on the next round of select(). I would like to receive the full message at once so that I will know which socket to forward the reply to (buffering will not work, since I don't know which message belongs to which when there are multiple clients). Is there a way to do this without blocking on read while waiting for a null character to arrive?

Comment: A non-blocking read is just that -- a read that won't block. It won't guarantee the entire message is there at once. It is imperative that you utilize a buffer if you want to progressively build the whole message from the input.

Comment: In addition, you don't need to be including a socket descriptor in the message... that sounds like a rather bad design.

Comment: Instead of having a list of socket descriptors, consider having a list of structures, this structure containing the socket descriptor _and_ a buffer to write to. Then you can keep track if the buffer is full or you have a complete message for each connected socket easier.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. But, when I receive a message from the server, how will I know which client to forward it to without it being a complete message? Even in the struct case, how will I know which buffer to insert the message?

Comment: You know which socket it came from. That socket is unique to that client.

Comment: @user1190650: You must already have some data structure somewhere that is holding the association between sockets.

Comment: When you have a complete message in the buffer, you can check it to see what to do with it. That is what buffering is all about; You receive a little, put it in the buffer, receive some more, put it in the buffer, notice you have a complete message, parse the message and do things with it. As for knowing which struct (and buffer) to put received data you have the clients socket descriptor in the socket, just loop over all structures, and if the socket is in the read-ready set then read from the socket into the buffer.

Comment: My question is for when a return message comes from the server. The socket connection will be from the proxy to the server. How will I then know which client to forward this message to?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as a message in TCP. It is a byte stream protocol. You write bytes, it sends bytes, you read bytes. There is no guarantee how many bytes you will receive at any one time and there is no guaranteed association between the amount of data written by a single write and read by a single read. If you want messages you must implement them yourself. Any given read may read zero, one, or more bytes, up to the length of the buffer. It might be half a message. It might be one and a half messages. What it is is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ZeroMQ if you're doing individual messages. It has bindings for a huge number of languages and is a great abstraction for networking. In fact, it can handle this proxy model for you.